# Problema con video embed de YouTube en vista movil CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo una duda con la vista de un video embed de YouTube, en vista de escritorio todo esta bien pero cuando cambio a vista móvil el video no se ve e incluso se pierde el nav bar.

```css
videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}
videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 700px;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <figure>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/H775uVQ-wB4" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy probablemente sea por la propiedad **Left:700px**
intenta quitarla y ver si aun se pierde al irte a vista móvil, en caso de que todo funcione bien entonces Tenes que agregar un media query algo así:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   videoWrapper iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   left: 5px;
   width: 10%;
   height: 10%;
 }
```

}